# How to get a method that returns 1 to 54 excluding the numbers passed in the argument?

Tags: java, methods, arguments

So I am currently asked to do a project that writes a method that returns a random number from 1 to 54, excluding the numbers passed in the argument.

http://pastebin.com/eeeYW3FX

```
public class randomNumberChooser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRandom(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                                                11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                                                21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
                                                31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,}));
    }

    public static int getRandom(int... numbers) {
            long time;
                int result;
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                result = (int)(time % 54) + 1;
                for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                        if(numbers[i] == result) {
                                break;

                        }
                }
                return result;
        }//end of main
}//end of class
```

But the problem persists as the numbers generated from the method are still passed and not excluded.

Comment: And what have you done yourself? And why do you think people here are just your servants?!

Comment: Please post code here and not post a link to code.

Comment: Although @AmirPashazadeh was quite rude and very non-constructive, he right in saying that you need to provide us with your code, show us what you have done yourself to figure it out and we can then help you from there.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: And this site has a very good built in code display so use it rather than redirecting us, it is just as easy to put it here as it is to put it there, unless it directs us to a working example.

Comment: OK. Is anything wrong with your code? Do you have a question?

Comment: Instead of just posting your code and telling us the assignment, Also explain the problems you're running into with your code, how it doesn't work, what it outputs, and what you expect it to output.

Comment: Yes @PM77-1 if you run the code it generates a number from 1 to 54 but the problem is that it generates that number but does not exclude it.

Comment: True. You simply didn't write that part of the code. You just break from your for loop. That's not enough for your task. When you determine that your number shouldn't be returned, you need to force the code to go back and generate another one.

Comment: Then what should I add to accomplish?

Comment: `if( numbers[i] == result )` you need to generate a new random number and then check to make sure it's not in that list. Try putting a while loop around your for loop.

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: The current time is not a good random number. Consider to use `Random.nextInt` or `Math.random` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first write a method to check if the number is within the array (`contains`), then call it... perhaps with something like this

```
// check if the array numbers contains the element n.
public static boolean contains(int[] numbers, int n) {
  if (numbers != null && numbers.length > 0) {
    for (int i : numbers) {
      if (i == n) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
} // end of contains

public static int getRandom(int... numbers) {
  long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for (;;) { // loop forever.
    int result = (int) (time % 54) + 1;
    if (!contains(numbers, result)) { // until the result ISN'T within numbers.
      return result;
    }
  }
} // end of getRandom
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I'm seeing is that the result is only derived once. So if the search contains the result, your method will still return it. Here's an a list of things you can think about

- Use a while loop.
- Obtain a new `result` each iteration
- Use the `for` loop to check if that result is in the array
- If the result is in the array, continue the loop.
- If is is not found, return the `result`

So ultimately your method structure can loop something like this. I will just give you a layout. You can try and figure the rest out on your own.

```
 public static int getRandom(int... numbers) {
     long time;
     int result;

     while (true) {
         time = ...
         result = ...

         boolean found = false;

         for (... ; ... ; ... ) {
             if ( ... ) {           // if you find it
                 found = true;
                 break;
             }
         }

         if (!found) {         // if the result is not found in the     
             return result;    // array, return it.
         }                   
     }
     return -1;  // dummy value to return, since a method must return something
 }               // Note: this method should never return -1 though. It will
                 // continue looping until the number is found
```